# Coroutin To Perform task

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-coroutines

hi this is my user repository

```
class UserRepository(private val appAuth: FirebaseAuth) : SafeAuthRequest(){

  suspend fun userLogin(email: String,password: String) : AuthResult{
     return authRequest { appAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)}
  }
}
```

this is the SafeAuthRequest class

```
open class SafeAuthRequest {
  suspend fun<T: Any> authRequest(call : suspend () -> Task<T>) : T{

    val task = call.invoke()
    if(task.isSuccessful){
        return task.result!!
    }
    else{
        val error = task.exception?.message
        throw AuthExceptions("$error\nInvalid email or password")
    }
  }
}
```

calling above things like that

```
  /** Method to perform login operation with custom  */
fun onClickCustomLogin(view: View){
    authListener?.onStarted()

    Coroutines.main {
        try {
            val authResult = repository.userLogin(email!!,password!!)
            authListener?.onSuccess()
        }catch (e : AuthExceptions){
           authListener?.onFailure(e.message!!)
        }
    }
}
```

and my authListener like this

```
interface AuthListener {
  fun onStarted()
  fun onSuccess()
  fun onFailure(message: String)
}
```

I am getting an error as the task is not completed

is the correct way to implement the task

Comment: maybe error is within appAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(), what is this function doing?

Comment: no erro what i am saying i want perfom the completed things but when task.issuccesful is false that means the task is not completed i want to perform these things   if(task.isSuccessful){
        return task.result!!
    }
    else{
        val error = task.exception?.message
        throw AuthExceptions("$error\nInvalid email or password")
    } after the completion of the task

Comment: `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method returns a promise. It's an asynchronous call.  You need to add `onCompleteListener` or something. https://joebirch.co/2019/10/03/using-firebase-on-android-with-kotlin-coroutines/

Comment: Maybe call.invoke() is not suspending instead its running async as the above comment says

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using MVVM architectural pattern, so the example I'm going to provide is called from my `ViewModel` class, that means I have access to `viewModelScope`. If you want to run a similar code on `Activity` class, you have to use the Coroutines scope available for your Activity, for example:

```
val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
uiScope.launch {...}
```

Answering your question, what I've done to retrieve login from user repository is this:

```
//UserRepository.kt
class UserRepository(private val appAuth: FirebaseAuth) {

    suspend fun userLogin(email: String, password: String) : LoginResult{
        val firebaseUser = appAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).await()  // Do not forget .await()
        return LoginResult(firebaseUser)
    }
}
```

LoginResult is a wrapper class of firebase auth response.

```
//ClassViewModel.kt
class LoginFirebaseViewModel(): ViewModel(){
    private val _loginResult = MutableLiveData<LoginResult>()
    val loginResult: LiveData<LoginResult> = _loginResult

    fun login() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                repository.userLogin(email!!,password!!).let {
                    _loginResult.value = it
                }
            } catch (e: FirebaseAuthException) {
                // Do something on firebase exception
            }       
        }
    }
}
```

The code on Activity class would be like this:

```
// Function inside Activity
fun onClickCustomLogin(view: View){

    val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main)
    uiScope.launch {
        try {
            repository.userLogin(email!!,password!!).let {
                authResult = it
            }
        }catch (e : FirebaseAuthException){
            // Do something on firebase exception
        }
    }
}
```

One of the main benefits of using Coroutines is that you convert asynchronous code in sequential one. That means you don't need listeners or callbacks.

I hope this help you